# Problem with the QuotChap package

Tags: positioning

I am using the package `quotechap` for making chapters beautiful. It is working fine but the problem happens in the content and bibilography section. My code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1.25in,rmargin=1in}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{emptypage}

%\usepackage{mathrsfs}


\usepackage{titlesec}
%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{black}}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
  [{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,mathtools}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage{quotchap}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
    \input{abstract.tex}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
 \clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Table of contents %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
    \include{ch1}


\vspace{-4.0\baselineskip}
\textbf{\begin{flushright}
        {\LARGE \textbf{BIB}}
\end{flushright}}
\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
\bibliography{thesisref}
\end{document}
```

Using this, the content heading is being placed at the top right in a weird and bad place. I have no idea how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: The line `\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}}` in your code is shifting the Contents header higher up the page, so try commenting that out.